# Israeli officials taking responsibility for a miscalculation in predicting a possible Hamas attack

Tags: government, israel, 2023-israel-hamas-war

I read in the news that the Israeli Defense Minister took responsibility for the 7/10 Hamas threat assessment/attack miscalculation (unfortunately I can't find a reference to this).

Is this true?

Did other Israeli officials also issue statements like that?

Is it international practice for government agencies/state leaders to take responsibility for such miscalculations?

By taking responsibility, I mean 1) a public statement “I/and my department/ are responsible for this event and its consequences. 2) As the @StuartF rightly mentioned, an adequate (from the public’s point of view) reaction could be resignation.

Shifting the blame to another person/organ has, in my opinion and as @Fizz indirectly mentioned in his response, a completely different ethical value.

Comment: It surely isn't an individual miscalculation. The whole secret service or defense ministry would probably take some blame. On the other hand with hindsight everything appears more clear than it really is when it is happening. Apart from this, quite often single persons take the blame or seem to be forced to take the blame. It is practice to present somebody.

Comment: I think you'll have to be more precise when asking who took responsibility in such situations: what do you mean by taking responsibility, by whom, and following what kind of events. While there are cases of resignation, e.g. Lord Carrington after the Argentine invasion of the Falklands, many others from Pearl Harbor to 9/11 didn't see much taking of blame by America or the UK (I won't go into whether it was justified or would have been good or bad to take the blame even if justified). The 2004 Madrid Train Bombings are another big example of buck-passing.

Comment: Well, there's at least one politician who doesn't:  [Netanyahu](https://www.timesofisrael.com/netanyahu-self-styled-peerless-leader-refuses-to-accept-he-presided-over-catastrophe/)  [and again](https://www.economist.com/briefing/2023/10/25/israels-prime-minister-and-its-army-are-damagingly-divided)

Comment: Thanks and when you 'read in the news' can you Post details of which publication you were reading?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - I read on the internet some time ago, but I don't even know how to find this source. The answers and comments below describe this circumstance in detail, even to a much greater extent.

Comment: Gosh… and then we wonder why slight slips in understanding cause wars? Oops!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I read in the news that the Israeli Defense Minister took responsibility for the 7/10 Hamas threat assessment/attack miscalculation (unfortunately I can't find a reference to this). Is this true?

Yes, Gallant [said](https://www.timesofisrael.com/liveblog_entry/gallant-takes-responsibility-for-failure-to-stop-terror-onslaught-on-southern-israel/) something like that:

> Defense Minister Yoav Gallant says he is taking responsibility for Hamas’s onslaught on southern Israel on October 7.
>
> “I am responsible for the defense establishment. I was responsible for it in the last two weeks, even in the difficult incidents, and I am responsible for bringing it to victory in the battle,” Gallant says to the press at a military assembly ground near the Gaza border.

---

> Did other Israeli officials also issue statements like that?

Some of them [did](https://www.timesofisrael.com/idf-intel-chief-says-he-bears-full-responsibility-for-not-warning-of-hamas-attack/).

> “The Military Intelligence Directorate, under my command, failed to warn of the terror attack carried out by Hamas,” Haliva said. “We failed in our most important mission, and as the head of the Military Intelligence Directorate, I bear full responsibility for the failure.”

Also of interest [perhaps](https://www.timesofisrael.com/netanyahu-sharply-criticized-for-post-blaming-intelligence-chiefs-for-oct-7-failure/)

> In a late-night tweet Saturday night, Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu repeated previous claims that he was not warned by security chiefs about an impending Hamas attack, and claimed all security chiefs had consistently assured him Hamas was deterred, drawing sharp criticism over the apparent attempt to blame them and evade responsibility for the disaster. He deleted the post some nine hours later, and issued a rare apology shortly afterward.

FT [editorialized](https://www.ft.com/content/32c75cfc-d94f-4fa1-a2ed-b91f8ba90296) some 10 days ago:

> The head of military intelligence for the Israel Defense Forces said he bore “full responsibility”, the boss of Shin Bet admitted his security agency “failed to give warning” of the assault and the IDF chief of staff said the military “did not achieve” its responsibility to prevent the slaughter.
>
> Yet one senior Israeli leader has conspicuously avoided shouldering responsibility, much less apologise for it: Benjamin Netanyahu, the prime minister who has led the country for much of the past 15 years.

Wikipedia [quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronen_Bar) Shin Bet's head, Ronen Bar's statement as:

> In an all-staff memo made public on Monday, 16 October 2023, Bar took responsibility for failing to thwart the 7 October 2023 attack by Hamas militants. "The responsibility is mine. Despite a series of actions we carried out, unfortunately, on Saturday we were unable to establish sufficient deterrence so as to thwart the attack," he wrote. "There will be time for investigations. Now we are fighting."

[And](https://www.news18.com/world/i-am-also-responsible-ex-israeli-pm-bennett-bears-responsibility-for-october-7-attack-8630445.html)

> Israel’s former Prime Minister Naftali Bennett has said that he also bears responsibility for the failure to anticipate the deadly attack by Hamas on October 7. Bennett, who served as PM from June 2021-2022, said there were things he didn’t have time to do and then the government fell.
>
> “Of course I also bear responsibility. I served as prime minister for 12 months. There were things I didn’t have time to do and then the government fell. Certainly, I bear responsibility,” Bennett was quoted as saying by The Times of Israel. He later put a post on social media platform X, in which he wrote, “I am also responsible.”

As for "international practice" it's rather hard to make an overall assessment. Probably a lot depends on the political culture in a country.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have knowledge about the historical context of admitting one’s guilt/taking responsibility for certain events. I just read that the practice of taking responsibility exists even among terrorist organizations. That is, in a sense, they also have a “political culture”.

Comment: @user545: I don't see many statements like that in Russian political culture, for instance. IMHO, it's more prevalent in the West, but there's plenty of "passing the buck" there too.

Comment: From what I've heard whether he admits it or not Netanyahu is going to be held responsible as soon as there is some sort of cease fire.   I heard his long political career might be over.

Comment: @JMS There is precedent for that in Israeli history.  Israel being surprised by the 1973 war did lead to the end of Golda Meir's political career.

Comment: @JustMe,  Agreed and Ehud Barak, PM in 2001 was taken out by the security concerns over the Second Intifada.  Kicked off by Ariel Sharon provocative visit to the Al-Aqsa compound.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it international practice for government agencies/state leaders to take responsibility for such miscalculations?

There's no such thing as "international practice". However, there are reasons why any given government figure may choose to do this, some more or less "valid" (often a subjective call), some more or less applicable to THIS specific situation. There reasons could be one of the following (the list obviously isn't complete, and more than one reason could be involved in anyone's decisions at the same time).

One last point to note - all the reasoning below is typically far more applicable/effective in society/institutions with democracy/representation, and free press - especially when most of the press is on the side of opposition as is the case in Israel today.

1. Actual human honesty/integroty. The official feels bad, and feels internally ethically required to accept responsibility. Humans are notoriously bad/lacking at this type of behavior - and government/power figures even more so - but *not everyone fully lacks honesty and integrity*, as hard as it may be to believe from observing politics. Something as awful as this very well may wake up ethics in someone, especially if they want to view themselves in good light later.
2. They think that accepting responsibility is LESS of a liability than NOT accepting. Most people already blame you, possibly for good reasons. So, if you accept responsibility, you're not increasing your problems (everyone already thinks you are responsible), BUT you are at the very least decreasing your problems by not looking like a self-righteous lying tool who isn't willing to take responsibility (and conversely, if you do NOT take responsibility, you do look like one, adding to your problems).
3. This takes away ammunition from your critics/opponents. There's less impact from "Leader of opposition accuses figure X of Y", when "X" admitted to "Y" themselves. Now opposition's accusations look more like partisan bickering and NOT attempt to "get at the truth and force accountability", which it would if responsibility wasn't taken.
4. They view it as morale-building - somewhat similar to #2 in mechanism; but the goal isn't personal (to look less like a tool) and more "statesmanlike", to increase populace morale by making leadership look better. This is especially potent in military (or even other professional) contexts, where many people value honesty and transparency in professional context - for good reasons.
5. You are "falling on your sword" to help your superior. In other words, by accepting responsibility at level "N" (boss's underling) you're protecting your boss (level N+1) from being blamed. Either out of fear, or out of loyalty, or in exchange for something.